# Python parabolic shooting animation with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the problem that circle is not an iterable, how do I solve it? I'd like the parabolic shot to work with the circle.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML

plt.style.use('dark_background')
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-5, 25), ylim=(-5, 25))
patch = plt.Circle((1, -1), 0.5, fc='b') #figura

X = 30
Y = 30
gravity=9.81
angle=70
velocity=80
vx=velocity * np.cos(np.radians(angle))
vy=velocity * np.sin(np.radians(angle))
t=0

def setup():
    patch.center = (10, 10)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch

def throwBall():
    global X, Y,  gravity, t,vx,vy

    t +=0.02
    X = vx*t
    Y = 400 -(vy*t - (gravity/2)*t*t)

    patch.center = (X, Y)
    return patch


animen = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, throwBall,init_func=setup,frames=360,interval=15,blit=True)

HTML(animen.to_html5_video())
```

Comment: Some remarks:  fig is not defined, throwBall should get 1 parameter, throwBall and setup should `return patch,`. The comma at the end is important, because it creates a tupple (with one element). A tupple is iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what @JohanC said. According to [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation), if `blit=True` "func must return an iterable of all artists that were modified or created." Therefore, you must return a list or a tuple of Artists, even if there only one artist modified.

I've also made some cosmetic changes. If you are incrementing `t` in your update function, why not pass directly the value of t as an argument to your update function using `frames = np.arange(0,7.2,0.02)` or something equivalent.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.patches import Circle


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(0, 500), ylim=(0, 500), aspect='equal')
patch = Circle((1, -1), 10, fc='b')
ax.add_patch(patch)

X = 30
Y = 30
gravity=9.81
angle=70
velocity=80
vx=velocity * np.cos(np.radians(angle))
vy=velocity * np.sin(np.radians(angle))

def setup():
    patch.set_center((X, Y))
    return (patch,)

def throwBall(t):
    global X, Y
    X = vx*t
    Y = 400 -(vy*t - (gravity/2)*t*t)
    patch.set_center((X, Y))
    return (patch)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, throwBall, init_func=setup, frames=np.arange(0,7.2,0.02), interval=20, blit=True)
```

Comment: In my formula I could be wrong, since it doesn't give me a parabolic shot.